# How to use string recieved by interface

Tags: android, android-activity, callback, fragment

Ive got an Activity with 2 Fragments. Now that the interface to send Data from one Fragment to my Activity is implemented, I want to display my Data (string) in an Textview. But how am I able to do this?
Ive got the method:

```
@Override
public void sendText(String dataInput) {

}
```

But how do I get access to my string?

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, AddDataFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.scanbutton);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Hier kann man später QR-Codes scannen", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        Fragment fragment;
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragment = new ListViewFragment();
        ft.replace(R.id.container, fragment);
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        ft.commit();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

     @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
     @Override
     public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
         Fragment fragment;
         FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
         fragment = new ListViewFragment();
         int id = item.getItemId();

             if (id == R.id.nav_listview) {
                 fragment= new ListViewFragment();

             } else if (id == R.id.nav_add_data) {
                 fragment= new AddDataFragment();

             } else if (id == R.id.nav_settings) {

             } else if (id == R.id.nav_legal_information) {
                 fragment = new LegalInformationFragment();
             }
         ft.replace(R.id.container, fragment);
         ft.addToBackStack(null);
         ft.commit();

         DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
         drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
         return true;
     }


    @Override
    public void sendText(String dataInput) {
        return;
    }
}
```

AddDataFragment:

```
public class AddDataFragment extends Fragment {

    Button buttonadd;
    Button buttondelete;

    private EditText inputProduct;
    private EditText inputLabel;
    private EditText inputSerial;
    private EditText inputMac;
    private EditText inputDaaId;
    private EditText inputBill;

    private TextView listElement;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add_data, container, false);
        inputProduct = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText_product);
        inputLabel = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText_label);
        inputSerial = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText_serial);
        inputMac = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText_mac);
        inputDaaId = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText_daa_id);
        inputBill = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText_bill);
        buttonadd = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button_add_addData);
        buttondelete = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button_delete_addData);

        final String Bsp = "BEISPIELEINTRAG 1234214124";

        buttonadd.setEnabled(true);
        buttondelete.setEnabled(true);

        buttonadd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String dataInput = inputProduct.getText().toString() + inputLabel.getText().toString() +
                        inputSerial.getText().toString() + inputMac.getText().toString() +
                        inputDaaId.getText().toString() + inputBill.getText().toString();

                mListener.sendText(dataInput);
            }

        });

        return view;
    }

    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        void sendText(String dataInput);
    }
}
```

I only want to send my Data from AddDataFragment to my ListViewFragment. Someone said that it would be the best way to communicate via interfaces...

EDIT: Am I right that I can use AddFragments Data only in the sendText method in my MainACtivity? The question is how to display this string. Sorry for Beginner questions...

Comment: I don't know what you mean. The string is a parameter that is passed into the sendText.. could you maybe add some more code and say which code belongs to activity and which to fragment

Comment: If the Fragment is created within the Activity you don't need an interface to access its data. Also the Activity must 'implement' the inteface in order to pass the information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interfaces in android are for callbacks from a 'child' to a 'parent'. For example your activity creates a fragment and tells him that he is the delegate that implements `OnFragmentInteractionListener`. The fragment can then trigger the code in the activity by calling `mListener.sendText(dataInput)`. Excellent.

However, because you want to send your data to another fragment (not to the parent activity) this is not a good way to go.

```
           Activity
          /       \
Fragment A         Fragment B
```

It is easy to communicate from Activity to fragment A and back. Likewise for B, but it is not easy to communicate from fragment A to B directly. At least not with interfaces.

You are probably better off storing your `dataInput` in sharedpreferences (or somewhere else) temporarily so you can store them in AddDataFragment and easily retrieve them in your ListViewFragment.

Comment: So you say that I shouldnt use Interfaces. Instead I should save my input in (for example) sharedpreferences?

Comment: @Rastaman it depends a little bit on what you do with the data in ListViewFragment, but if you just want to show the data when the fragment becomes visible, then yes